# Adam Optimizer and Regularization in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I've been creating a CNN using the Adam Optimizer. My model has been really overfitting so I decided to add some regularization. I initially thought that adding the "kernel_regularization" parameter to each convolutional layer and collecting all the regulaizations and adding it to the loss would work. All this does to my network is make it learn what it did without the regularization much slower but there is still overfitting after many more epochs.

However, reading around a bit it looks like that regularization is not the correct way to go when using Adam in Tensorflow, but I could not find a definitive answer on this.

If someone could please clarify and direct me on how to add regularization when using the Adam optimizer, I would be very grateful.

EDIT: A little more description about the task

I am doing a binary segmentation task using a UNet architecture.

Comment: Did you lower the learning rate or increase the betas? https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/AdamOptimizer

Comment: More information about your task, data, model, loss function etc. would help because it's hard to make a statement without knowing the details.

Comment: I did lower the learning rate.

Comment: Describe "However, reading around a bit it looks like that regularization is not the correct way to go when using Adam in Tensorflow, but I could not find a definitive answer on this." precisely. Why did you begin to think regularization is not the correct way to go when using Adam?

Comment: If your model is "really overfitting", then that might indicate that your approach (e.g. architecture, loss, training schedule) is inadequate for the task. While regularization can help, it is not a miracle solution to overfitting. By the way, I don't think there is any problem with using regularization and Adam.